# How can i include the debug info in my binary?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, pdb-files

I have a C++ application, using VS2008, and i want to include the debug information into the binary so that i don't need to publish the ".pdb" file with my application. My application has made use of the dgbhelp.dll, and i do need those debug information so that i can get the source code line number when there's exception occurred. But without the ".pdb" file, my application failed to get the line number, and it would be better if i can include the debug info in the ".pdb" file into the binary.

Comment: Why? Windows works differently from Linux, and you probably have to accept that. You don't have to strip your binaries to hide the debug info, but instead you need to publish the .pdb files if you *want to* make the symbol info available.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, you need `/Z7` instead of `/Zi`.  (I've never tried it though.)